# Error with script that calls another script with different shell

Tags: shell-script, shell, scripting

I have a script which runs in sh shell, this script runs fine. But I've added one script written in ksh shell ( in the head of the script there is #!/bin/ksh) but every time i get the error

```
./monitor_FMn2.sh[19]: 104:  not found
```

Which every time change the second line that hit the error
The 19th line is the line where i call the ksh script

```
if `wc -l < $LOGFILE` > 55;
    then
    logcycle $LOGFILE
fi
```

**logcycle** is the ksh script.

Comment: Where is your `logcycle` script, please specify the full path in your sh script, that is safer ... your `sh` cannot find the file in question. is `logcycle` executable ?

Comment: logcycle is based on a directory which is declared in PATH ( /home/oracle/FM2/scripts/logcycle) and is executable 
-rwxr-xr-x   1 oracle   dba         2189 Nov 28 14:33 /home/oracle/FM2/scripts/logcycle.
The sh script can find it, otherwhise i shouldn't have the error, right?

Comment: Change `logcycle`  to `ksh /home/oracle/FM2/scripts/logcycle` in your script, does that work ?

Comment: @thecarpy thanks for having a look. maybe i haven't been clear enough earlier, logcycle is in ksh already, is the other script that is not, it's in sh

Comment: Please clarify, which line is which ? In fact, I think you should check Steephane's answer, I guess he is on track ... `$LOGFILE` had 104 lines when this error occurred, and the faulty line IS NOT `logcycle $LOGFILE` as your question implies but the `if` statement above that ...

Comment: @thecarpy yes, i followed Stephane's suggestions, as you can see from the below comment, and it works now. Thanks for the interest in this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
`wc -l < $LOGFILE` > 55
```

Runs the command whose name is the output of `wc` subject to split+glob (104 in your case) and redirects its output to a file called `55` in the current directory. As there's no command called 104 on your system, you get that error.

Presumably, you wanted to write:

```
if [ "$(($(wc -l < "$LOGFILE") +0))" -gt 55 ]; then...
```

That is run the `[` aka `test` command (instead of `104`) to test that the output of `wc -l` interpreted as an arithmetic expression (so `[` doesn't complain about leading spaces if any) is greater than 55.

Or with ksh syntax:

```
if (($(wc -l < "$LOGFILE") +0 > 55)); then...
```

(the `+0` to cover for the case where the `wc -l < "$LOGFILE"` command produces no output, like when the `$LOGFILE` cannot be opened for reading).

(you may also want to remove that empty `55` file created earlier by your script).

Comment: thanks Stephane, i knew was a syntax error. I used the first option

`if [ "$(($(wc -l < "$LOGFILE")))" -gt 55 ]; then...`

and it work as i wanted. Many thanks indeed